# rake assets:precompile misses jquery-ui-rails files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, activeadmin

It seems that active_admin has some missing dependency blocking `rake assets:precompile` to succeed:

```
rake aborted!
Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.datepicker'
  (in /home/avril14th/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/active_admin-8ec04cfbf8fd/app/assets/javascripts/active_admin/base.js.coffee:2)
```

active_admin depends on jquery-ui-rails and browsing the gem file tree yields the file properly. It just means that the assets precompile can't reach it.

I use rails 4.1.4.

how should one deal with this?

Comment: I'm in the same boat with Rails 4.1.4 and using the active_admin Gem straight off of Github

Comment: Here's the issue I posted on the active_admin repo: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/3253

Comment: Also, it seems this is being worked on: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/pull/3251

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is being worked on here: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/pull/3251

The solution presented there that worked for me was:

In active_admin.js.coffee there exists this line:

```
#= require active_admin/base
```

Change it to this:

```
#= require jquery
#= require jquery-ui/datepicker
#= require jquery-ui/dialog
#= require jquery-ui/sortable
#= require jquery-ui/widget
#= require jquery_ujs
#= require_self
```

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that the latest version of jquery-ui used a hyphen ('jquery-ui/datepicker') instead of a point ('jquery.ui.datepicker'). 
You have to add jquery-ui-rails gem in your Gemfile, and must be the version '4.2.1', that is currently used to activeadmin

Add to your Gemfile

```
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 4.2.1'
```

Runs `bundle update`, and voila, all works fine

Comment: I added gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 4.2.1' in my Gemfile and run bundle update but still the version is 5.0.0 and I still have the error Sprockets::FileNotFound at /
couldn't find file 'jquery.ui.all' Please Help